# Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 3.0 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

When I list restaurant with Flutter I get this error message:

```
Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 3.0 pixels on the right
```

[image]

Source code:

```dart
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
    child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned.fill(
                child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Container(height: 210, child: Loading()),
            )),
            Center(
              child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                  placeholder: kTransparentImage, image: restaurant.image),
            )
          ],
        )),
);
```

Comment: @Kebson [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (15652): Receiver: null
E/flutter (15652): Tried calling: []("id"

Comment: new RestaurantModel.fromSnapshot (package:foodapp/models/restaurant.dart:43:24)
E/flutter (15652): #2      RestaurantServices.getRestaurantById.<anonymous closure> (package:foodapp/helpers/restaurantHelpers.dart:22:32)

Comment: <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15652): #5      RestaurantProvider.loadSingleRestaurant (package:foodapp/providers/restaurantProvider.dart:22:18)
E/flutter (15652): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (15652):Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 2.0 pixels on the right.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap it in an Flexible widget

```dart
Flexible(child: 
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
        child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned.fill(
                    child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Container(height: 210, child: Loading()),
                )),
                Center(
                  child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                      placeholder: kTransparentImage, image: restaurant.image),
                )
              ],
            )),
      );
```

Comment: I put flexible but no change Kebson    [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
E/flutter (15652): Receiver: null
E/flutter (15652): Tried calling: []("id")